# Ignoring properties in RavenDB 3.5 (.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, ravendb, ravendb-3.5

Is there any way to ignore a property in a RavenDB entity class for RavenDB 3.5?
I'm working on upgrading a project to .NET core and this project relies on RavenDB.
Before when saving an object to RavenDB I could just add the attribute JsonIgnore from the Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json namespace in the Raven.Abstraction library to the property I wanted to be ignored but this library doesn't seem to exist for 3.5.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way, the client is embedding the attribute, and it is available.

Comment: Wasn't recognized in my code since im using multiple frameworks which confused me. Got it working now though, thanks!